# SMB for specific user from DMZ to internal

Tags: network-share, dmz

I've got one server in a DMZ which has limited access via SMB  to another one in the internal network. A web server on that external machine needs access to a whole partition on that internal server.

I'm still using a quick and dirty solution. the web server still runs as a SYSTEM user. I managed to mount the share for that user.

The main problem: this setup is not reboot-safe. After a reboot the connection has to be re-established, because there's no way to save the credentials fot hat share.

P.s. the DMZ server is not in the windows domain

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: the Web Server is a Windows machine in your DMZ, with IIS running under the SYSTEM account?  Not ideal (as the SYSTEM account is not *supposed* to have access to network resources) but possibly doable, in a lab environment.

In any case, it sounds like you need to issue a `NET USE` to the target server, under the context of the SYSTEM user.

Scheduled Tasks can be run under the SYSTEM account.

Putting these together, how about creating a Scheduled Task with the following settings:

- **Action**: `"%WINDIR%\system32\net.exe" USE \\TheSmbServer\TheNetworkShare /USER:TheDomain\TheUser Th3_P@55w0rd`
- **Logon User**: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (use blank password -- Windows will manage)`
- **Trigger/Schedule**: `At system startup`
- **Options**: `Run whether user is logged in or not`; `Run with highest privileges`

That *should* bind the necessary authentication credentials at (or close to) startup.

If it needs to be able to access all shares, try using `\\TheSmbServer\IPC$` as the share.

Comment: Good idea, but as you already said, it's not the best idea running those services as SYSTEM, which I want to change of course. In this case it's a single partition z$ which will be accessed. I assume this should be possible with the correct domain user / rights. I'll test it later today

Comment: `Z$` as in, the default admin share `\\TheSmbServer\Z$`?  You will probably need to grant local Administrator rights to TheServer.  If you have to give access to a logical drive (i.e. `Z:`) for non-administative users, I would create a new explicit share and set permission appropriately on the share object itself (e.g Change/Read), rather than using the default admin shares.